# Use regular PropTypes checks inside a custom validator

Tags: react-proptypes

I started out with a very simple PropTypes validation:

```
name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
```

Now I need to only have string be required if a certain other condition is false, so:

```
name: ({name, otherProp}) => {
  if (otherProp === 'foo') return null;

  if (typeof name === 'string') return null;

  return new Error('Error');
}
```

Which is fine in this case, but what I'd really like to be able to do after the first check is run the regular PropTypes check for `string.isRequired` inside my custom validator, like maybe:

```
name: ({name, otherProp}) => {
  if (otherProp === 'foo') return null;

  return PropTypes.string.isRequired;
}
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this with `PropTypes.checkPropTypes`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered while poking around the code for Material UI a clever way to do something equivalent to this: parallel prop-types checks. They have a very simple utility function [chainPropTypes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d7993b558e25baa347ee07601d36dd3960a97975/packages/material-ui-utils/src/chainPropTypes.js) which goes like this:

```
export default function chainPropTypes(propType1, propType2) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return () => null;
  }

  return function validate(...args) {
    return propType1(...args) || propType2(...args);
  };
}
```

You use this to do a custom prop types check along with a standard check. For example [like this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d7993b558e25baa347ee07601d36dd3960a97975/packages/material-ui/src/Popover/Popover.js#L442):

```
  anchorEl: chainPropTypes(PropTypes.oneOfType([HTMLElementType, PropTypes.func]), (props) => {
    if (props.open && (!props.anchorReference || props.anchorReference === 'anchorEl')) {

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom PropType which can take a PropType as an argument.

```js
export const myCustomPropType = (propType, otherProp) => {
    return function validate(props, propName, ...rest) {
        const originalPropType =  propType(props, propName, ...rest);
        if (props[otherProp] === 'foo') return originalPropType;
        if (typeof props[propName] === 'string') return originalPropType;
        return new Error('Error');
    };
};
```

Usage

```js
MyComponent.propTypes {
    myProp: myCustomPropType(PropTypes.string.isRequired, 'otherPropName')
}
```